# Android : Resizing a drawable

Tags: android, image-resizing

I am working on an android application and I want to reduce my icones. 
I have tried different ways but each time the returned drawable has a low density..
However when I resize the same image on photoshop, it keeps a good density.
The following code is the best that I found.

Could you help me to improve it please ?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView newImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Bitmap unscaledBitmap = decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.test2, 120, 120, ScalingLogic.FIT);

            newImage.setImageBitmap(createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, 120, 120, ScalingLogic.FIT));
    newImage.setImageBitmap(createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, 120, 120, ScalingLogic.FIT));



}

public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
        ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }


    public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }


    public static enum ScalingLogic {
        CROP, FIT
    }


    public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }


    public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
                final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
                return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
            } else {
                final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
                final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
                return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
        }
    }


    public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
    ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
            } else {
                return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use 9-patch images where you will defined stretchable area. These areas are defined in a special 1 pixel wide border around the area because Custom drawn buttons can look distorted and pixelated when their borders are stretched in addition to the rest of the image on other hand 9-patch images scale separately. This is handy for mobile devices that have smaller screens with differing resolutions and aspect ratios. Take a look at this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLimJf-EIl8)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I cannot custom all the images one by one because there are around 1,000 images exctracted from a file..